# Not understanding geometric sum

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't need whole example just one step in calcualting, I need to calculate Laurent serie of function, but first I need to write one part in geometric sum.

So they have:

$g(z)=\int \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}dz= \frac{1}{1-z}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k, \left | z \right |< 1\ 
 & \\ 
-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{z})^k, \left | z \right |> 1\ 
 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Can someone explain me how they get this sums, okay first one is clear, but I don't have idea about second one.

Comment: Thank you. I correct it. @LutzL

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|>1$, then $|w|<1$ where $w=\dfrac1z$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{w}{w-wz}=-\frac{w}{1-w}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty w^k.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|>1$ then $\dfrac{1}{|z|}<1$ and so $$\dfrac{1}{1-z}=-\dfrac{1}{z}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=-\dfrac{1}{z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{z^k}$$